# Assert that certain elements exists among others independent of order

Tags: xsd

I'm importing data from an xml feed built like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<channel>
  <item>
    <a>some data</a>
    <b>some data</b>
    <c>some data</c>
  </item>
  <item>
    <c>some data</c>
    <d>some data</d>
    <b>some data</b>
  </item>
</channel>
```

Only some data is important to me -- in the example above, let's say the data in elements `<b>` and `<c>`.

The next item might contain a tag named `<g>`, `<e>`, or why not `<p>`. Other tag names  than those I'm interested in are unknown to me and may occur at any time.

Is there any way for me, with xsd, to validate that the elements I'm interested in (`<b>` and `<c>`) exists within all `<item>`s?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Not exactly the way I wanted. I used the same approach as you suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an xsd you could explain that the element is mandatory.

**e.g**

```
    <xs:complexType name="item">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
```

In this way you should only apply an xsd validation.

- `<xs:all>` indipendent of order
- `minOccurs="1"` mandatory element

I hope I've given you all the answers about your question.

Comment: Point is-- I don't know the name of all items available. However, I'm marking this as the answer as it is the way I ended up doing it. 
The problem with this approach is that when the feed I'm validating against changes in a way I'm not actually interested (say adds an element e), I have to update my xsd.